# CGFloat division crash

Tags: objective-c, operators, cgfloat

I have this code:

```
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n%g pixel \n=======================================",screenWidth]);
    CGFloat imageWidth = [[self.widthArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] floatValue];
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n%f pixel\n=======================================",imageWidth]);
    CGFloat ratio = screenWidth / imageWidth;
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"\nratio is %f\n=======================================",ratio]);
```

`screenWidth` and `imageWidth` is perfectly fine, but when I try to log `ratio` the program just crashes and the log says `(lldb)`. I still haven't found the solution yet anywhere. Any Sugestions?

EDIT:

the first two log is

```
2015-01-03 08:49:00.888 Huckleberry[6554:158359] 
320.000000 pixel 
=======================================
2015-01-03 08:49:00.889 Huckleberry[6554:158359] 
512.000000 pixel
=======================================
```

and then the `ratio` is just `(lldb)`

Comment: 1. what are the values? 2. Research `NSLog()`, it is not necessary to use `stringWithFormat`. Ex: `NSLog(@"\n%g pixel\n=======================================", screenWidth);`

Comment: Research `NSLog()`, it is not necessary to use stringWithFormat. Ex: `NSLog(@"\n%g pixel\n=======================================", screenWidth);`. Further the format string for `NSLog()` should be a literal, Xcode even warns about this.

Comment: For 32 bit platforms `CGFLoat` is defined `float`, for 64-bit platforms `CGFLoat` is defined `double`.

Comment: Does it crash or do you simply have a breakpoint on that line?

Answer (score 1):

If you see `(lldb)` in the console you've most likely hit a breakpoint. If you haven't added a breakpoint there yourself there might be an exception breakpoint in your project, catching all uncaught exceptions.

Try clicking on the "play" looking button above the console, that should continue the execution (or at least help you with what the crash was).

Answer (score -1):

```
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
NSLog(@"Screen width = %f pixel", (float) screenWidth);
CGFloat imageWidth = [[self.widthArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] floatValue];
NSLog(@"Image width = %f pixel", (float) imageWidth]);
CGFloat ratio = screenWidth / imageWidth;
NSLog(@"ratio is %f", (float) ratio]);
```

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question. It's good code cleanup but it doesn't explain anything or solve the issue in the question.

Comment: @rmaddy - It fixes the operand length problem in the format strings.

Comment: But there is no operand length issue. `%f` can be used with both `float` and `double`.